# "must declare scalar variable" when using gridview

Tags: asp.net, t-sql

i have two gridviews on a webform in asp.net with c# code behind. i also have 3 tables: user, group and usergroup.

one gridview contains a list of groups with two columns: description and a buttonfield. when the user clicks on this buttonfield, the members of the selected group should be displayed in the second gridview.

however, i get an error "must declare scalar variable @GruppenID every time i click the buttonfield. what am i missing here? sorry but i am completely new to asp and sql...

## WORKING:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Gruppenverwaltung.aspx.cs" Inherits="WerIstWo.Gruppenverwaltung" %>

<asp:Content ID="content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <h1>Gruppenverwaltung</h1>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlGruppe" ScrollBars="Both" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btnNeueGruppe" Text="Neue Gruppe" runat="server" OnClick="btnNeueGruppe_Click" />
        <asp:GridView DataKeyNames="GruppenID" OnRowCommand="grdGruppe_RowCommand" ID="grdGruppe" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Bezeichnung" HeaderText="Bezeichnung" SortExpression="Bezeichnung" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mitglieder anzeigen">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnMitgliederAnzeigen" runat="server" Text="Mitglieder anzeigen" CommandName="MitgliederAnzeigen"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("GruppenID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Archivieren" ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource OnSelected="SqlDataSource1_Selected" ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Bezeichnung], [GruppenID] FROM [Gruppe] WHERE [Archiviert] != 1"
            DeleteCommand="UPDATE Gruppe SET [Archiviert] = 1 WHERE [GruppenID] = @GruppenID">            
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Button ID="btnZurueck" Text="Zurück" runat="server" OnClick="btnZurueck_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel Visible="false" ID="pnlMitglieder" ScrollBars="Both" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="grdBenutzer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Vorname" HeaderText="Vorname" SortExpression="Vorname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Nachname" HeaderText="Nachname" SortExpression="Nachname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Geburtsdatum" HeaderText="Geburtsdatum" SortExpression="Geburtsdatum" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT  a.Vorname,
                           a.Nachname,
                           a.Geburtsdatum
                           FROM [Benutzer] a
                           INNER JOIN [BenutzerGruppe] b
                           ON a.BenutzerID = b.BenutzerID
                           INNER JOIN [Gruppe] c
                           ON b.GruppenID = c.GruppenID
                           WHERE c.GruppenID = @GruppenID">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="GruppenID" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Zurück" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WerIstWo
{
    public partial class Gruppenverwaltung : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["UserAuthentication"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }
        }

        protected void btnZurueck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Datenverwaltung.aspx");
        }

        protected void btnNeueGruppe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("NeueGruppe.aspx");
        }

        protected void grdGruppe_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "MitgliederAnzeigen")
            {
                string index = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                pnlMitglieder.Visible = true;
                pnlGruppe.Visible = false;
                SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["GruppenID"].DefaultValue = index;
                grdBenutzer.DataBind();             
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlMitglieder.Visible = false;
            pnlGruppe.Visible = true;            
        }

        protected void SqlDataSource1_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you passing `@GruppenID` command parameter to query ?

Comment: sorry but like i said, i really am new to this stuff...almost everything you see in the code above has come from other posts on this site...i thought since it is on the same page, the variable will be available from the other gridview

Comment: use `<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="GruppenID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
  </SelectParameters>` in sql data source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass SqlDataSource Select Parameter.

As you are new a whole process should be like this as your need

add CommandArgument property in button Field

```
  // <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandArgument="GruppenID"   CommandName="MitgliederAnzeigen" Text="Mitglieder anzeigen" /> 

   replace this to

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mitglieder anzeigen">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Mitglieder anzeigen" CommandName="MitgliederAnzeigen"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("GruppenID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

your SqlDataSource2 must be

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="select a.Nachname,
        c.GruppenID
        FROM [Benutzer] a
        INNER JOIN [BenutzerGruppe] b
        ON a.BenutzerID = b.BenutzerID
        INNER JOIN [Gruppe] c
        ON b.GruppenID = c.GruppenID
        WHERE   c.GruppenID = @GruppenID
         ">    
    <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="GruppenID" />
</SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

now on row command

```
if (e.CommandName == "MitgliederAnzeigen")
        {
 string index = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
           pnlMitglieder.Visible = true;
           pnlGruppe.Visible = false;  
              SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["GruppenID"].DefaultValue = index;
              grdBenutzer.DataBind();

        }
```

Comment: i get an parser error when i put the CommandArgument in the buttonfield tag...it says that ButtonField has no static property CommandArgument (sorry if this is a little lost in translation, the error is in german)

Comment: @LeonidasFett sorry was in hurry to answer, updated my answer

Comment: its still not working...now i get a NullReferenceException in this line: SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["GruppenID"].DefaultValue = index; in the RowCommand Method

Comment: this mean you're getting null in string , try to give an existing groupid eg SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["GruppenID"].DefaultValue= 10

Comment: weird, it wasnt null when i debugged...also hardcoding a value does give the same error...

Comment: ok now the NRE is gone, but i get an SqlException: "The multi-part identifier "Benutzer.BenutzerID" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "BenutzerGruppe.BenutzerID" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "BenutzerGruppe.GruppenID" could not be bound." in this line:grdBenutzer.DataBind();

Comment: try to run your query *select a.Nachname,
       c.GruppenID
        FROM [Benutzer] a
        INNER JOIN [BenutzerGruppe] b
        ON a.BenutzerID = b.BenutzerID
        INNER JOIN [Gruppe] c
        ON b.GruppenID = c.GruppenID
        WHERE   c.GruppenID = 10// any existing group id* in sql server and see the result

Comment: thanks i googled the error and the answer that helped me is the same as yours...now its working flawlessly...thanks again for your patience and help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the SQL parameter @GruppenID in `SqlDataSource1` for both the `SelectCommand` and the `DeleteCommand`, like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource OnSelected="SqlDataSource1_Selected" ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Bezeichnung], [GruppenID] FROM [Gruppe] WHERE [Archiviert] != 1"
    DeleteCommand="UPDATE Gruppe SET [Archiviert] = 1 WHERE [GruppenID] = @GruppenID">

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="GruppenID" />
    </SelectParameters>

    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="GruppenID" />
    </DeleteParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

You can then set the values for this parameter like in [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/949925.aspx/1).

Comment: ok when i try this, i get no more output in my first gridview. now its just empty

Comment: This is because you need to set the value to be passed through the `@GruppenID` parameter when the `MitgliederAnzeigen` command is invoked (in `grdGruppe_RowCommand`).